# 'self' keyword requires an authenticated user

Tags: instagram

I have very strange behavior with some users on my web app using Instagram API.

The problem is that I authenticate them and save their token, and all works fine. I can make requests to get media, comments, in other words I can do all. Except one thing, with **some** users when I try to access `v1/users/self` I get in response:

> Instagram::BadRequest: GET
>   https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self.json?access_token=xxx&client_id=xxx&sig=xxx:
>   400: 'self' keyword requires an authenticated user

And again it is **only on this endpoint** because I can get information from other endpoint without any problem..

Do you have any suggestions on what I can do?

My Instagram ruby gem configuration:

```
Instagram.configure do |config|
    config.client_id = ENV['INSTAGRAM_client_id']
    config.client_secret = ENV['INSTAGRAM_secret']
    config.sign_requests = true
end
```

Comment: Am i wrong or there is no endpoint as /users/self? https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: Try your request in browser by entering url in address bar or using postman. Check whether it succeed or not.

Comment: @RishikesanVaradharajan tried it before. Same response

Comment: The accesstoken might be expired. Get a new accesstoken and try it. For this api endpoint client_id is not required as a parameter.